# Convert 2D array to a 1D array with certain exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hey guys this is reverted thing from my previous question. Not solved yet. but making the simple requirement that i need a code that will do convert my 2D array into 1D array with an condition. i.e.

```
A[0,2,3,7,0,0,5,3][0,2,2,4,0,0,3,0]
```

and i want this as result

```
B[2,2,4,3,0]
```

This does mean i want those values which are not zero from 2D array's second coloumn.

Comment: you can iterate through it na and assign values to a single array..

Comment: why minus points to this ??

Comment: Sry may be u do not understand what i am asking for ..... i want A[1] where A[0] != 0 respected members

Comment: Can you work to make your question clearer? It's very difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var checkBox = [Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4, Array5, Array6];
var dataOfUS = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6];

for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < checkBox.length, j < dataOfUS.length; i++) {
if (checkBox[i].length > 0) {
                    arrays[k] = dataOfUS[j];
                    k++;
                }
                j++;
            }
```

Try this might work surely

Answer (score 0):

`A[1].filter(function(i){return i!=0;})` should give you what you want.

Comment: Sry may be u do not understand what i am asking for ..... i want A[1] where A[0] != 0

Answer (score 0):

use array filter

```js
var A=[[0,2,3,7,0,0,5,3],[0,2,2,4,0,0,3,0]];
var B = A[1].filter(function(v, i) {
    return !!A[0][i];
});
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = B;
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Sry may be u do not understand what i am asking for ..... i want A[1] where A[0] != 0 respected members

Comment: may be i am damn forget about that the numbers are length of perticular array...... there are array in those place of numbers